# When I Run PowerShell script always changes back to User Directory

Tags: powershell

Strange issue I've not seen. Started working somewhere new so not sure if it's a quirk but each time I run a PS Script the first thing it seems to do is change back to my user DIR (c:\Users\UserName)

seems to do this at the start of the script because if I output any files that's where they end up (obvs unless I use explicit path)

Bit annoying I'm gonna try work out why it's doing it but thought I'll ask a bunch of smarter people.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: Check out if there's anything in the [six(!) Powershell profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Actually I've just worked out what is doing it. Will post below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick reply guys I dind't notice when connecting to Exchange Online with MFA it goes to that the userprofile folder.

```
$CreateEXOPSSession = (Get-ChildItem -Path $env:userprofile -Filter 
CreateExoPSSession.ps1 -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Select -Last 
1).DirectoryName
. "$CreateEXOPSSession\CreateExoPSSession.ps1" Connect-EXOPSSession -UserPrincipalName  myUPN
```

It's early morning here I need a coffee!!

thanks again